# Is a vector field not a vector quantity?

Tags: vectors, tensor-calculus, vector-fields, covariance, poisson-brackets

I'm trying to make sense of Poisson bracket relation

$$\{L_i,A_k\}_{PB}~=~\epsilon_{ikl}A_l,\tag1$$

where $L_i$ is $i$th component of angular momentum, $A_k$ is $k$th component of an arbitrary vector, and $\epsilon_{ikl}$ is Levi-Civita tensor.

When I take $\vec A$ to be position, momentum or angular momentum, I can confirm that $(1)$ is true. But if I take $\vec A(\vec r)$ to be an arbitrary vector field, e.g.
$$\vec A=\cos\left((x-3)^2y\right)\vec e_x+(y+2z)\vec e_y+2\cos\left((y-3)^2z\right)\vec e_z,\tag2$$
 $(1)$ appears to be false. Moreover, somewhere I've read that arbitrary vector can be written as 
$$\vec A=\phi_1\vec r+\phi_2\vec p+\phi_3 (\vec r\times\vec p),\tag3$$
where $\phi_i$ are arbitrary scalar functions and $\vec r$ and $\vec p$ are position and momentum vectors. And $(2)$ can't be written in the form $(3)$.

Does this mean that an arbitrary vector field is not a vector quantity? What does the "vector" word mean in this term then?

---

**EDIT**: based on the answers and after some experimenting I seem to have found that $(1)$ should be true for such $\vec A(\vec r,\vec p)$, which for arbitrary rotation $R$ satisfies

$$R\vec A(R^{-1}\vec r,R^{-1}\vec p)=\vec A(\vec r,\vec p).\tag4$$

At least, $(4)$ is satisfied by $\vec r$, $\vec p$ and $\vec L$, while not satisfied by $(2)$.
This seems to be what @Qmechanic calls *dynamical active vector*. Am I right? Where to read more about this notion? Googling this phrase doesn't seem to give anything related.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Read where?

Comment: @Qmechanic do you mean where I've read about $(3)$? See e.g. [Landau, Lifshitz "Mechanics" $\S42$ problem 4](https://archive.org/stream/Mechanics_541/LandauLifshitz-Mechanics#page/n145/mode/2up).

Comment: @Ruslan Landau and Lifshitz write that any vector field that *only depends on position and momentum* can be decomposed in that manner. In general this is valid only in 3D (where the cross product is defined) and only if $x$ and $p$ are not parallel (i.e. if $x \times p \neq 0$).

Comment: @Neuneck how does $(2)$ not satisfy your italicized statement? It depends only on position $(x,y,z)$ and momentum (constant in $\vec p$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comments to the question (v3):

I) The notions of [vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_%28mathematics_and_physics%29), tensors, scalars, etc, depend on contexts in physics, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32011/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41211/2451) Phys.SE posts and links therein.

II) In OP's context, these notions refer to representations $\rho$ of the Lie group $SO(3)$ [and the corresponding Lie algebra $so(3)$] of 3D rotations, cf. e.g. Ref. 1. Let $\mathrm{i}L_k$, $k=1,2,3$, denote the $3$ antisymmetric real $3\times 3$ matrix generators of $so(3)$: 
$$\mathrm{i}(L_k)_{ij}~:=~\epsilon_{ijk}.\tag{A}$$

In this context, a *vector$^1$* $V_k$ is an object that transforms in the 3-dimensional vector (or triplet) representation $\bf 3$ of $SO(3)$. Concretely this means that $$(\rho(\mathrm{i}L_k)V)_i~=~\epsilon_{ijk}V_j,\tag{B}$$
up to sign conventions. Similarly, a *scalar* $S$ is an object that transforms in the 1-dimensional trivial (or singlet) representation $\bf 1$ of $SO(3)$. Concretely this means that $$(\rho(\mathrm{i}L_k)S)_i~=~0.\tag{C}$$

*Example:* OP's vector field (2) can be viewed as an element in the vector representation of $SO(3)$. Not surprisingly, the [group action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) of a rotation $R\in SO(3)$ on the vector field leads to rigid rotations of the vector field (2). However, the vector field (2) is not a dynamical active vector, see next section III.

III) In the Hamiltonian formalism, for objects constructed out of e.g. $x_i$, $p_j$, $\delta_{ij}$, $\epsilon_{ijk}$, etc., and contractions thereof, there is also another notion. Let us for the purpose of this answer call it the notion of *dynamical active* vectors, tensors, scalars, etc. E.g. a *dynamical active vector* $V_k$ satisfies by definition
$$ \{L_i,V_j\}_{PB}~=~\epsilon_{ijk}V_k\tag{D}$$
where
$$L_i~:=~\epsilon_{ijk}x_jp_k\tag{E}$$
is the orbital angular momentum, and
$$\{x_i,p_j\}_{PB}~=~\delta_{ij}~=~-\{p_i,x_j\}_{PB},\quad \{x_i,x_j\}_{PB}~=~0~=~\{p_i,p_j\}_{PB},\tag{F}$$
is the [canonical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_coordinates) [Poisson brackets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket) (PB). Similarly, a *dynamical active scalar* $S$ satisfies
$$ \{L_i,S\}_{PB}~=~0.\tag{G}$$

*Example 1:* Consider the inner/dot product $S=a_kx_k$, where $a_k$ is a constant (dynamically passive) vector. Then $S$ is a scalar (C), but $S$ is not a dynamical active scalar (G).

*Example 2:* The inner/dot products $S=x_kx_k$, $S=x_kp_k$, $S=p_kp_k$, and $S=a_ka_k$ are all dynamical active scalars according to definition (G).

*Example 3:* A linear combination 
$$V_k~=~\sum_a S_{(a)} V_{(a)k},\tag{H}$$ 
of dynamical active vectors $V_{(a)k}$ with dynamical active scalar coefficients $S_{(a)}$ is again a dynamical active vector (D).

*Example 4:* The three objects $x_i$, $p_j$, and $L_k$ are all dynamical active vectors according to definition (D). In fact, these three objects constitute a basis for dynamical active vectors, in the sense of eq. (H), cf. Ref. 2 and OP's eq. (3).

References:

1. G. 't Hooft, [*Introduction to Lie Groups in Physics*](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/lectures/lieg.html), lecture notes; chapter 3 + chapter 9. The pdf file is available [here](http://www.phys.uu.nl/~thooft/lectures/lieg07.pdf).
2. L.D. Landau & E.M. Lifshitz, *Mechanics,* vol. 1, 1976; $\S$42. Problem 3 & 4. Note that L&L have the opposite convention for the Poisson bracket (PB) as compared to eq. (F).

--

$^1$ We assume here that the metric $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$, and hence will not distinguish between covariant and contravariant indices, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119126/2451) Phys.SE post. Also we assume Einstein summation convention, i.e. summation over repeated indices.

Comment: So, as I understand you, in 4. and 5. you contrast $A_k$, the function of a single phase space point, with $(2)$, a function of position $\vec r$. But what if we view $(2)$ as a function of phase space point $(\vec r,\vec p)$, which just doesn't depend on $\vec p$? What's the major difference between these two types of functions then? Or, going backwards, why isn't e.g. $\vec A(\vec r)=\vec r$ a vector field, which would also rigidly rotate under $R$?

Comment: So what is the definition of dynamical active vector — is it (D)? My vector $(2)$ is also constructed of $x_i$ (if we view it just as a function of current $\vec x$), but still doesn't satisfy (D). Should the dynamical active vector be linear in $x_i$ and $p_i$ or what?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The Poisson bracket you wrote only works for position (which is not a vector in general, as coordinates do not transform as vectors or any other tensor quantity). For general vectors the correct Poisson bracket is
$$\{L_i,A_m\} = - (\mathbf p\times\nabla_{\mathbf p} + \mathbf r\times\nabla)_i A_m,$$
which reduces to the relation you wrote if you take $A_m = r_m$.

As for the decomposition, that must work every time $\mathbf r$ is not parallel to $\mathbf p$, as in this case $\mathbf r,\mathbf p,\mathbf r\times\mathbf p$ is a set of independent vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ and therefore they constitute a basis.

Comment: Hmm, does this hold for quantum commutator of the operators of corresponding quantities? I've taken $(1)$ from the commutator given as $(29.4)$ in [this book](http://tinyurl.com/mqa6nbk) and just checked that it works for $\vec r$. The authors of the book talk about radius vector as of a vector, while you say it's not a vector. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: the angular momentum generates the rotations around the axis given by its direction, so the radius "vector" gets rotated and therefore it looks like it behaves like a vector. The same confusion occurs in special relativity, where the position vector transforms with Lorentz transformations, but of course one can consider coordinate changes which are not linear.

Comment: I still don't get in what cases position of particle doesn't transform as vector? Also, the Poisson bracket $(1)$ works not only for position but also for momentum, and even for angular momentum although it's a pseudovector. Do all three of these not transform as vectors?