# Difference between position of indexes in Kronecker delta symbol

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, covariance, dirac-matrices

I am studying the Dirac gamma matrices and have encountered the Kronecker delta $\delta_{ij}$ That I am accustomed to. However, I have also come across a different form, $\delta_{\mu}^{\nu} $.

This particular example comes from deriving a very simple expression:
$$\gamma_\mu\gamma^\mu=\delta_\mu^\mu$$
How is this delta different from the one with both indexes lowered? Is there any additional meaning besides emphasizing the position of the indexes on the LHS?

Comment: Do you understand covariant and contravariant indices and how to raise and lower them with the metric tensor?

Comment: Yes, I understand how to do it in any given matrix, say $\gamma_\mu=\eta_{\mu\nu}\gamma^\nu$. But I don't understand that meaning in the delta matrix. Isnt the delta matrix just a matrix with 1s in the diagonal and 0s elsewhere?

Comment: Yes. When you raise an index on $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ you get $\eta^\mu_\nu$, but this is just $\delta^\mu_\nu$ because of how the inverse metric is defined: $\eta_{\mu\lambda}\eta^{\lambda\nu}\equiv\delta_\mu^\nu$.

Comment: Note that $\delta_{ij}$ is a tensor under rotations but $\delta_{\mu\nu}$ is not a tensor under Lorentz transformations; it isn’t even defined as far as I know.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119126/2451 and links therein.