# Gradient is covariant or contravariant?

Tags: vectors, tensor-calculus, vector-fields, covariance

I read somewhere people write gradient in covariant form because of their proposes.
I think gradient expanded in covariant basis $i$, $j$, $k$, so by invariance nature of vectors, component of gradient must be in contravariant form. However we know by transformation properties and chain rule we find it is a covariant vector. What is wrong with my reasoning?

My second question is: if gradient has been written in covariant form, what is the contravariant form of gradient?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105347/2451 and links therein. Cross-posted to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/868819/11127

Answer (score 19):

Most of the answers posted here are incorrect. The Wikipedia page for the gradient says

> The gradient of $f$ is defined as the unique vector field whose dot product with any vector $v$ at each point $x$ is the directional derivative of $f$ along $v$.

A look at Theodore Frankel's *The Geometry of Physics* confirms this. Other posters have said that the components of the gradient of $f$ are given by $\partial_i f$; these are in fact the components of the differential of $f$, which is a covector. The gradient is this with the index raised.

Let's now calculate both sides of the expression from Wikipedia. The inner product of $\mathrm{grad}(f)$ with a vector $v$ is
$$
\mathrm{grad}(f)^{i} g_{i j} v^j =\mathrm{grad}(f)^i v_i.
$$
The directional derivative of $f$ along $v$ is
$$
D_v f = v^i \partial_i f = g^{ij} \partial_i f ~v_j.
$$
We can clearly identify
$$
\mathrm{grad}(f)^{i} = g^{ij} \partial_j f
$$
or
$$
\mathrm{grad}f = g^{-1} \mathrm{d} f.
$$

Comment: Your post is true given your definition, but here's another true statement: On a coordinate patch $(x,y,\cdots)$, the list $(\partial_x f,\partial_y f,\cdots)$ transforms as the components of a one-form! IMO the most natural definitions for manifolds (the "true" definitions) are the ones that still have meaning even when no metric is defined, but your/wikipedia's definition makes use of the metric. I would argue that makes the definition not fundamental.

Comment: Yes, it is less fundamental than the differential. Anyway, it is very common for physicists to call this object the gradient (as seen in this thread). In physics, we virtually always have a metric, so it is more or less irrelevant.

Answer (score 16):

Gradient is covariant! Why?

The components of a vector *contravariant* because they transform in the inverse (i.e. contra) way of the vector basis. It is customary to denote these components with an upper index. So, if your coordinates are called $q$'s, they are denoted $q^i$.

Therefore, the gradient (or a derivative if you prefer) is $$\partial_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial q^i},$$ which transform as the inverse of the component transformation  ( 1 / contra-variant = co-variant ).

---

If you're still not convinced... try this!

- Propose a coordinate transformation -This is a transformation rule for the *contravariant* components- (e.g. from Cartesian to Polar)
- Use the *chain rule* to transform the derivative,
- Check that the transformation of the derivative is the inverse of the coordinate transformation.

---

**Personal Note:** Although the notation my homonym Oscar point out  is correct [say $\partial^i$], I prefer to avoid it, because is not a derivative wrt the "real" coordinates. Please do not misunderstand my words... It is Ok to define that operator, but should be treated carefully!

Cheers! ;-)

Comment: I like your answers regarding covariance and contravariance. You mentioned in some other post that you teach a class. Are the lecture notes posted online somewhere? Would love to take a look!

Comment: @PhotonicBoom Unfortunately no! I've had no enough time to work on that... but it is in my todo list! In any case, you can find some academic material on my webpage https://sites.google.com/site/ocastillofelisola/Home/academic/methods (It is messy 'cause there are files I wrote as a student and the concepts were not matured). See for example `GR00`

Comment: @Dox- thank you for your answer. I know we can show the covariance nature of gradient components by using chain rule. But in fact my question is: Do you agree that if a vector expands by covariant bases, its components must transform in contravariance form, by the invariance nature of vector ? If so, gradient expanded by i, j, k (covariant bases), so its components are contravariant. Am I true ?

Comment: @aminliverpool Yes and No! Yes to your first comment "Do you agree that if a vector expands by covariant bases, its components must transform in contravariance form, by the invariance nature of vector?". But, No to the second "If so, gradient expanded by i, j, k (covariant bases), so its components are contravariant. Am I true?"... unfortunately, on Euclidean space there is no quantitative difference between co- and contra- variant components of a vector, so people tends to mix their rol. $i$, $j$ and $k$ are basis for contra-vector (not for co-vectors), they don't expand the gradient! :-)

Comment: @Dox. Ok. Thank you. Is it possible for you, for an orthogonal coordinate system, write gradient in contravariance and covariance form ?

Comment: @Dox- Excuse me. I should say for a "nonorthogonal coordinate system" instead of "orthogonal system".

Comment: @aminliverpool The relation between their component is given by the metric (used for raising or lowering indices).

Comment: This answer is not correct. The gradient is distinct from the derivative: the definition of the gradient boils down to "the vector corresponding to the differential of a scalar function", i.e. $ (\vec{\nabla} f)^i = g^{ij}\partial_j f$.

Comment: @ZachMcDargh It is a matter of interpretation. Of course you are right if insist in associating a *contravariant* vector to a perfectly well behaved geometrical object... personally, I stick to the covariant object, specially for teaching since most students get confused at the beginning with all of the indices gymnastic.

Comment: Sure, it is a well behaved covariant object. But the question is about the gradient, which is defined as a contravariant vector. The object most answers here refer to is the differential.

Answer (score 9):

Recall the integral definition of the gradient:

$$\nabla \varphi = \lim_{V \to 0} \frac{1}{V} \oint_{\partial V} \varphi \hat n \, dS$$

This should tell you the gradient's components transform the same way as those of the normal vector $\hat n$, which is known to have covariant components.

You can verify that the normal vector has covariant components by recalling that the normal can be defined through a cross product of tangent vectors (which have contravariant components; the cross product of true vectors is a pseudovector, which has covariant components), for instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know we can show the covariance nature of gradient components by using chain rule. But in fact my question is: Do you agree that if a vector expands by covariant bases, its components must transform in contravariance form, by the invariance nature of vector ? If so, gradient expanded by i, j, k (covariant bases), so its components are contravariant. Am I true ?

Comment: The Cartesian bases are the same whether they're covariant or contravariant, so I don't see how you can draw a conclusion from that.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Is it possible for you, for an orthogonal coordinate system, write gradient in contravariance and covariance form ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking me to do.

Comment: Excuse me. I should say for a "nonorthogonal coordinate system" instead of "orthogonal system". Do you agree gradient is a vector, so it can expanded by basis vectors? Ok. I want you in a nonorthogonal coordinate system, you expand gradient both in contravariance form(that is expanded by covariant basis) and covariance form (that is expanded by contavariant basis).

Comment: Obviously you can expand any such quantity in terms of either the tangent basis or the cotangent basis, but expanding the quantity $\nabla \varphi$ that I defined above would give you metrical terms if you expanded in terms of the tangent basis--it is *naturally* written in terms of the cotangent basis.

Comment: I need a concrete example. I want you to expand gradient in a nonorthogonal coordinate system in covariance and contravariance form. Your explanaion are general and I can understand it well.

Comment: $\nabla \varphi = \sum_i g^i \partial_i \varphi$, where each $g^i$ is a cotangent basis vector.  $g^i \cdot g_i = 1$ always, while $g^i \cdot g^j = g^{ij}$ gives you metrical components.

Answer (score 4):

A covariant vector is commonly a vector whose components are written with ``downstairs" index, like $x_{\mu}$. Now, the gradient is defined as $\partial_\mu := \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$. As you can see the covariant vector $\partial_\mu$ is the derivative with respect to the contravariant vector $x^\mu$. the contravariant form of $\partial_\mu$ is $\partial^\mu := g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu$ - and in case the metric is constant $\partial^\mu = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_\mu}$.

Sometimes the vector $\partial_\mu$ is used to indicate a coordinate basis of the tangent vector space in some point of a manifold. In that case the index $\mu$ is not the index of the component (that for a vector should be upstairs), but it indicates the $\mu$th vector of the basis.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Do you agree with me that covariant gradient expanded by covariant basis i, j, k ?

Answer (score 2):

Gradient is covariant. Let's consider gradient of a scalar function. The reason is that such a gradient is the difference of the function per unit distance in the direction of the basis vector.

We often treat gradient as usual vector because we often transform from one orthonormal basis into another orthonormal basis. And in this case matrix transpose and inverse are the same.

Let $E, E'$ be matrices of basis vectors and $A$ be the transformation matrix between them.

$$
(E')^T
 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{e}'_1 & \hat{e}'_2 & \vdots & \hat{e}'_n 
\end{bmatrix}
 = 
A
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{e}_1 \\ \hat{e}_2 \\ \dots \\ \hat{e}_n 
\end{bmatrix}
 = 
A\ E
$$

Let $\hat{v}, \hat{v}'$ be vectors in respective bases. Then
$$\label{1} \tag{1}
\hat{v} = v^i\hat{e}_i = E^T\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\ \vdots \\v_n\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\label{2} \tag{2}
\hat{v}' = v^i\hat{e}'_i = (E')^T\begin{bmatrix}v'_1\\v'_2\\ \vdots \\v'_n\end{bmatrix} = (A\ E)^T\begin{bmatrix}v'_1\\v'_2\\ \vdots \\v'_n\end{bmatrix} = E^TA^T\begin{bmatrix}v'_1\\v'_2\\ \vdots \\v'_n\end{bmatrix} $$
From $\ref{1}$ and $\ref{2}$ we have:
$$A^T\hat{v}' = \hat{v}$$
and finally
$$\boxed{\hat{v}' = (A^T)^{-1}\hat{v}}$$

Answer (score 2):

I'll offer a simple explanation that relies only on the slope.

Suppose we have a line with slope 5, so for every 5 units up there corresponds one unit to the right. Now let us dilate the y axis by 3, that is, the spaces between each increment of 1 is now 3 times larger. In order for our slope to be invariant (equal 5), the slope's y component must also dilate by a factor of 3, that is, **co-vary** with the y axis.

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to try to provide the simplest explanation of why the gradient is a covariant vector.

By definitions, the components of a covariant vector transform obey the law :
$$ \overline A_i = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac {\partial x^j} {\partial \overline x^i} A_j  \qquad \qquad (1) $$

and the the components of a contravariant vector transform obey the law :
$$ \overline A^i = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac {\partial \overline x^j} {\partial  x^i} A^j \qquad \qquad (2)$$

If the components of gradient of a scalar field in coordinate system $ \Bbb {\mathit {x_j}} $ , namely $ \frac {∂f} {∂x_j} $ , are known, then we can find the components of the gradient in coordinate system $ \Bbb { \overline { \mathit {x_i}}}$, namely $ \frac {∂f} {∂ \overline x_j} $, by the chain rule:

$$ \frac {\partial f} {\partial \overline x_i} = \frac {\partial f} {\partial x_1} \frac {\partial x_1} {\partial \overline x_i} + \frac {\partial f} {\partial x_2} \frac {\partial x_2} {\partial \overline x_i} + \cdot\cdot\cdot+ \frac {\partial f} {\partial x_n} \frac {\partial x_n} {\partial \overline x_i} = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac {\partial x_j} {\partial \overline x_i}\frac {\partial f} {\partial x_j}  $$

Obviously $ \quad \frac {\partial f} {\partial \overline x_i}=\overline A_i \quad $ , and $ \quad \frac {\partial f} {\partial x_j} = A_j \quad $, then we get the equation same as $ (1) \quad $

Therefore, the gradient is a covariant vector.