# Distinction between contraction and application of a tensor in abstract index notation

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, notation

A somewhat similar question is [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/380858/abstract-index-notation-for-general-relativity-wald) but it is not quite the same.

I am getting used to the abstract index notation used for tensor algebra. So far so good, but the is one issue that concerns me, In *General Relativity* by Wald, it is discussed how the difference between two connections $\tilde{\nabla}$ and $\nabla$ induces a tensor $C$ of rank (1,2)  in $T_pM$, and hence (by the index notation) we denote this tensor as ${C^c}_{ab}$. The problem is that Wald defines this tensor by the equation
$$\nabla_a\omega_b=\tilde{\nabla}_a \omega_b- {C^c}_{ab}\omega_c $$
Which seems funny, we can think of the last term in the RHS of the latter as the contraction of the (1,3) tensor $C\otimes \omega $  with respect to the first dual vector slot and the third vector slot. But rather than this odd way of deffining the tensor $C$ we could make use of the index-free notation. So that we could define the tensor $C:V^{*}\times V\times V\to \mathbb{R}$ as $$\omega,t,s\mapsto (\tilde{\nabla}\omega)(t,s)-(\nabla\omega )(t,s)   $$
which is what would be natural way of defining a tensor "by it's action". So the question is: Is my way of understanding the abstract index notation in this case is the correct one, or rather does the definition of Wald refers to $$\sum_{k=1}^nC(e^{k*},t,s)\cdot \omega(e_{k})=(\tilde{\nabla}\omega)(t,s)-(\nabla\omega)(t,s) $$
where $\{e_1,\ldots, e_n \}$ is some basis of $T_pM$ and $\{e^{1*},\ldots, e^{n*} \}$ is its dual basis. Which is it? How could one know using the Abstract index notation?

Note that the first definition (the one I assume is the correct one) does indeed define a tensor, meanwhile a tensor is hardly ever characterized by a contraction. But the notation, as defined does indeed suggest the contraction interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $$\nabla_a\omega_b=\tilde{\nabla}_a \omega_b- {C^c}_{ab}\omega_c$$
can be contracted with vector components $X^a$ and $Y^b$:

$$C^{c}_{ab}X^aY^b\omega_c = (\tilde{\nabla}_a\omega_b) X^aY^b - (\nabla_a\omega_b) X^a Y^b$$
which can be expressed in coordinate-free notation as

$$\mathbf C(\boldsymbol\omega,\mathbf X,\mathbf Y) = (\nabla_{\mathbf X}\boldsymbol \omega)(\mathbf Y) - (\tilde{\nabla}_{\mathbf X}\boldsymbol \omega)(\mathbf Y)$$

where $\nabla_\mathbf{X} =X^a \nabla_a$.  Note in particular that $\nabla_{\mathbf X}$, which is the covariant directional derivative along $\mathbf X$, maps a covector field $\boldsymbol \omega$ to a covector field

$$\nabla_\mathbf{X} \boldsymbol \omega = (X^a\nabla_a\omega_b)\hat \epsilon^b = X^a(\partial_a \omega_b -\omega_c \Gamma^c_{ab})\hat\epsilon^b$$

You can use this to go backwards to verify that the coordinate-free expression above does indeed yield the expression you started with.

---

Lastly, note that the $(0,2)$-tensor with components $C^c_{ab}\omega_c$ could equivalently viewed as the $(1,2)$-tensor $\mathbf C$ with the covector $\boldsymbol \omega$ plugged into the first slot (i.e. $\mathbf C(\boldsymbol \omega,\bullet,\bullet)$ ) or as the trace over the first and fourth index of the $(1,3)$-tensor ($\mathbf C \otimes \boldsymbol \omega$).  If I'm interpreting the question correctly, the answer is that your two alternate interpretations are equivalent.

Comment: Yes. I noted that! And that was actually the answer I expected. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to define the tensor ${C^c}_{ab}$ without using contractions using the Christoffel symbols for the connections. If you remember that
$$\nabla_a\omega_b=\partial_a\omega_b-\Gamma^c_{ab}\omega_c$$
$$\tilde{\nabla}_a\omega_b=\partial_a\omega_b-\tilde{\Gamma}^c_{ab}\omega_c$$
then the difference gives
$$\tilde\nabla_a\omega_b-\nabla_a\omega_c=(\Gamma^c_{ab}-\tilde\Gamma^c_{ab})\omega_c\tag{1}\label{key}$$
so that what Wald has called the tensor ${C^c}_{ab}$ is
$${C^c}_{ab}=\Gamma^c_{ab}-\tilde\Gamma^c_{ab}$$

It is a general result that the difference between two $\Gamma$ is a tensor, even though the $\Gamma$'s themselves are non-tensorial. You can check reasoning as follows: if the left-hand side of \eqref{key} is tensorial, because it is the difference between to covariant derivatives; then the right-hand side must also be a tensor. This is only possible if $\Gamma^c_{ab}-\tilde\Gamma^c_{ab}$ is a tensor. This is not just valid for the covariant vector $\omega_c$, you can do this reasoning in general by applying the covariant derivatives $\nabla$ and $\tilde\nabla$ to an arbitrary rank tensor ${T^{a_1a_2...a_m}}_{b_1b_2...b_n}$ and you will get the same result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my question was about what the translation of the definition of the tensor would be in non-index notation? I think I could have made that clearer. For that I apologize, I will up-vote your answer since it was helpful. I successfully wrote a translation in index free notation that the contraction definition really defines a unique tensor. The proof was almost immediate, but doing it made evident an important observation that I missed when getting into the Abstact Index Notation.