# Gradient of scalar field

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, vectors, differentiation, vector-fields

On page183 of Rayd'inverno "An introduction to relativity" he says that the right term in parenthesis is a gradient of some scalar field i.e.
When $$\partial_a (\frac{\ X_b}{\ X^2})=\partial_b(\frac{ X_a}{\ X^2}) ,$$ $X^2\neq0$ such that $$\frac{X_a}{X^2}=f, _a \tag 1$$ where $f$ is some scalar field.

How equation (1) happened? What is the reason behind it? I don't understand it please somebody explain to me.

Answer (score 2):

1. OP's eq. (1) follows from [Poincare lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms): The co-vector/1-form $$\omega~:=~\frac{ X_a\mathrm{d}x^a}{\ X^2}\tag{A}$$ is closed
   $$\mathrm{d}\omega~=~0,\tag{B}$$
   and hence locally exact, i.e. on the form $$\omega~=~\mathrm{d}f~=~f_{,a}\mathrm{d}x^a\tag{C}$$
   of a [differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_(mathematics)).
2. Note that a vector $X^a\partial_a$ and a co-vector $X_a\mathrm{d}x^a$ are related via the [musical isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism). This isomorphism also connects [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) vectors and differentials.

Comment: Can you please explain me the reason behind equation (1) within the concept of vector calculus instead of using the concept of 1-form?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: So after equating equation A and C we get gradient of scalar field but Does the concept of 1-form is necessary to really understand gradient?

Comment: This is related to [Is it foolish to distinguish between covariant and contravariant vectors?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105347/2451)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have that book, but if $\partial_a$, $\partial_b$ are Cartesian coordinates, the condition you provided are the coordinates of $\nabla \times \mathbf{F} = \mathbf{0}$,

with $\mathbf{F} = \dfrac{\mathbf{X}}{|\mathbf{X}|^2}$.

It's not hard to prove that $f = \ln \dfrac{|\mathbf{X}|}{X_0} $, by direct computation

$\partial_i f = \partial_i \left( \ln \dfrac{|\mathbf{X}|}{X_0} \right) = \dfrac{X_0}{|\mathbf{X}|} \dfrac{1}{X_0} \partial_i |\mathbf{X}| =\dfrac{1}{|\mathbf{X}|} \partial_i |\mathbf{X}|$

and remembering that $\partial_i |\mathbf{X}|= \frac{X_i}{|\mathbf{X}|}$ we eventually get

$\partial_i \left( \ln \dfrac{|\mathbf{X}|}{X_0} \right) = \frac{X_i}{|\mathbf{X}|^2}$

Given the condition on the curl, you can write $\mathbf{F}$ as the gradient of a scalar field, namely $\mathbf{F} = \nabla f$. Having established that, you can interpret the condition

$\partial_a \left( \dfrac{X_b}{X^2} \right) = \partial_b \left( \dfrac{X_a}{X^2} \right) $$\qquad \rightarrow \qquad$
$\partial_a F_b = \partial_b F_a$$\qquad \rightarrow \qquad$
$\partial_a \partial_b f = \partial_b \partial_a f$

with the Schwartz condition on mixed second derivatives.

Comment: So by definition gradient of scalar field is equal to vector divided by it's magnitude i.e $\nabla f=\frac{X}{X^2}$ (By definition) ?

Comment: no. I update my answer

Comment: By definition, the gradient of a scalar field is a vector field that gives you the direction of the maximum growth of the function and it's related to the directional derivative in direction indicated by the unit vector  $\mathbf{\hat{v}}$ by $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} =\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{f(\mathbf{x}+\alpha\mathbf{v}) - f(\mathbf{x})}{\alpha}= \mathbf{\hat{v}} \cdot \nabla f$